# "echo password | sudo -S" with exclamation mark

Tags: linux, bash, passwords, echo

What I want to do is

> $ echo password!p | sudo -S [command]

in a linux terminal (in my case, ubuntu20.04). If you type it as it is, the exclamation mark will refer to the history of the command line, and if !p=pwd, it will be a string like passwordpwd and will not send the password!p correctly. I have tried every way I could find to escape the exclamation, like 'password!p', 'password!p', '\''password!p'\'', etc. The last one behaves the same as 'echo |' but did not result in using the command. Is there any way to get through this?

Comment: Single quotes prevent string to be interpolated by shell, why don't use them? Also \! should work.

Comment: Also echo adds newline at the end by default. Use `echo -n` to prevent this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, in my environment, neither the \! nor single quotes did not solve the problem.

Comment: @Saga873 What weird environment do you have where single-quotes won't work for this? In bash, single-quotes absolutely should work for this.

Comment: I had a simple misunderstanding about this question. What I wanted to do was the following.

> echo password!p | sudo -S -u root [command].

This would not pass the root password, so I mistakenly thought it was because of the exclamation mark, but what I had to send here was the password for the current account that uses sudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could try turning off history expansion.

```
set +o histexpand
echo -n "password!p" | sudo -S command
set -o histexpand # if you want to restore the capability after
```